# Reading number from masked number input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert data into input, which transfers them into (xxx xxx xxx xxx)(with spaces every third number), i have masked input, and when I try to read data from input it doesn't work, I even need to read the input without spaces

PS: will be output in PHP with spaces?

```
<td>
  <input type="text" name="klient[podnikatelPrijem]" value="<? update($klient[podnikatelPrijem])?>" id="klientpodnikatelprijem" onkeyup="soucetPrijmu()"/>
</td>
```

```js
$('#klientpodnikatelprijem').inputmask("numeric", {
  radixPoint: ",",
  groupSeparator: " ",
  digits: 2,
  autoGroup: true,
  //suffix: ' Kč', //Space after $, this will not truncate the first character.
  rightAlign: false,
  oncleared: function() { 
    self.Value(''); 
  }
});

function soucetPrijmu() {
  var a = ((document.getElementById("klientzamestnanecprijem") || {}).value) || "";
  var s = ((document.getElementById("klientpodnikatelprijem") || {}).value) || "";
  var rocniPrijem = +a + +s;
  document.getElementById("klientsoucetprijem").value = rocniPrijem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've enabled `inputmask` on your inputs, the unmasked value can be get using [`unmaskedvalue()`](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#unmaskedvalue) function, and the standard `value` will not work.

For example, if you need to get the value of the textbox `#klientpodnikatelprijem`, you need to call

```
$("#klientpodnikatelprijem").inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
```